# PostgreSQL 8.3.7: "FATAL: could not reattach to shared memory" and "WARNING: worker took too long to start; cancelled"

Tags: postgresql, shared-memory, postgresql-8.3

We record our office IP phone activity using Xima software's Chronicall, which uses a PostgreSQL backend.  The server on which both of these are installed is an ESXi 5.5 VM running Windows Server Standard 2008 SP1.  For some time now, we have been getting the following PostgreSQL errors in Windows event viewer:

- "FATAL:  could not reattach to shared memory (key=248,
  addr=02510000): 487"
- "WARNING:  worker took too long to start; cancelled"

These errors occur every hour or two, and always occur back-to-back in the order listed above.

Xima support has looked at the issue multiple times and has not been able to resolve it.  Upon their recommendation, I have upgraded Java, disabled antivirus, and run the Windows Memory Diagnostic Tool (came back clean), but the errors persist.  Xima has specifically stated that PostgreSQL should not be updated, as versions above 8.3.7 are known to cause other issues with Chronicall.

Any other suggestions to resolve this issue?

Comment: I would ask the software vendor why the insist on using an outdated and unsupported version **especially** when the *first* issue in the changelog for 8.3.8 reads "*Fix Windows shared-memory allocation code ... This bug led to the often-reported "could not reattach to shared memory" error message*"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Very good question. That's like your car dealer telling you not to replace broken seatbelts or the car will stop running ...

Comment: BTW, to give you an idea of how stupid it is for them to ship 8.3.7, the 8.3.7 release was *2009-03-16*. The first 8.3 release was 2008-02-04. The final end-of-life patch release for 8.3 was in 2013-02-07. So they're shipping a major release that's *six and a half years old*, and they're doing so with a patch release that's over five years old, ignoring nearly four years of patches. That's absolutely nonsensical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say the company (Xima) is at fault here, since PostgreSQL 8.3.7 is hopelessly outdated.

Quoting the official [Versioning policy of Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/):

- Postgres 8.3 has reached EOL in Februar 2013
- Moreover, Postgres strongly recommends:

  > *We always recommend that all users run the latest available minor
  >   release for whatever major version is in use.*

  The latest point release of 8.3 is **8.3.23**.

Version 8.3.7 is **just not right**.
<sub>Running Postgres on a Windows Server 2008 VM wouldn't be my first idea either...</sub>

Comment: Agreed, I was taken aback by the company's decision to stay with an unsupported Postgres version rather than simply resolving any issues their software might have with newer versions.  They have now advised that I simply copy the 8.3.8 binaries into the postgres directory without performing a full database upgrade, so I suppose we'll see how that pans out.    EDIT: The error reoccurred within minutes of copying these binaries over.

Comment: @blasmat: Why not *at least* version 8.3.23?

Comment: @blasmat This issue was fully resolved in later PostgreSQL releases. It took a series of changes, and I think it was fully fixed around 9.0, so the fixes were probably back-patched into later point-releases in the 8.3 series. Read the release notes or git history to confirm. It's absolutely insane not to run 8.3.23, as it's 100% compatible and contains a very large number of bug fixes. It's also *incredibly stupid* of this application vendor not to ship a current, supported PostgreSQL version in the first place - at least 9.1 would be the minimum reasonable.