# Postgres 9.4 Crash

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I am running Postgres 9.4 on Windows Server 2012. I have had postgres crash a few times with the following error:

```
FATAL:  could not reattach to shared memory (key=00000000000000D0, addr=00000001405E0000): error code 1455
```

[Looking around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24614314/postgresql-8-3-7-fatal-could-not-reattach-to-shared-memory-and-warning-wor) it looks like this error was supposed to be fixed back in 8.3.

Around the time of the crash it appears to have free RAM available.

My server specs:

```
OS: Windows Server 2012 x64
CPU: Intel Xeon CPU 2.30GHz (x2)
RAM: 52GB
Postgres: 9.4.5
```

Some settings from postgres:

```
shared_buffers = 512MB
effective_cache_size = 39GB
work_mem = 90MB
maintenance_work_mem = 2000MB
```

Can anyone suggest what might be causing the crash? If you need more info please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: could you please share technical spec of DB server (cpu/ram )?

Comment: @DmitrySavinkov see updated answer.

Comment: Does it also happen in Postgres 9.5? This seems like a bug if it's something you can reproduce, but that should be taken up with the Postgres team directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to post this to the PostgreSQL project itself. They are a helpful and professional bunch.

There are [guidelines](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/bug-reporting.html) and a bug-reporting form [here](http://www.postgresql.org/support/submitbug/). They will want to know the exact version of 9.4.x as well as the hardware/OS details you've given above.

A [quick search of the bug mailing-list](http://www.postgresql.org/search/?m=1&l=8&q=windows%20reattach%20shared%20memory) has a similar-sounding post, but you'll probably want to try searches yourself.

It is also worthwhile checking the other [mailing lists](http://www.postgresql.org/list/) and popping onto general and just asking there too.

I don't run PostgreSQL on Windows in any serious sense, but this sounds like a bug - I would guess some corner case where shared-memory is handled differently on Windows than on other platforms. The crucial first step will be to pinpoint exactly where this error is being generated.

Comment: I posted a bug as you suggested and got some feedback. It looks like the number of connections is just too high on my server. The thread is here: http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/20160419123034.22924.9159@wrigleys.postgresql.org#20160419123034.22924.9159@wrigleys.postgresql.org

Comment: Hmm - reading that thread, I wouldn't be surprised if it was related to the high number of connections. Perhaps you hit 1024 and something in Windows doesn't like it. I'm familiar with running large numbers of databases on Linux, but not Windows. If it is fairly easy to do, it might be worth seeing if partitioning your databases into 2 VMs makes the problem go away. Obviously you'd need to consider any performance impact.